# How to clear the gesture in android?

Tags: java, android

I have a gestureview and i can draw anything in it, but when i want to put another drawing I need to clear the gesture on that activity. I used a clear button, but I cant figure out the exact method to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Write a `Handler` for the `GestureOverlayView`

```
public void onGesturePerformed(GestureOverlayView gestureView,Gesture gesture) {
    gestureView.setFadeEnabled(true);
}
```