# Android clear gesture

Tags: android, gesture

I have written an Android app to recognize gestures. If the gesture is recognized, I want to clear it.

In my OnCreate I have a `GestureOverlayView` and I am setting the fade enabled to true.

```
setFadeEnabled(true);
setFadeOffset(5000);
```

This is set so that if no gesture is input in 5 seconds it will fade out.

Now inside the `onGesturePerformed` method I am following the answer given here: [Clear Gesture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12740733/clear-gesture-from-gestureoverlayview-in-android)

and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9879823/how-to-clear-the-gesture-in-android)

```
 public void onGesturePerformed(GestureOverlayView overlay, Gesture gesture) 

{
    ArrayList<Prediction> predictions = gestureLib.recognize(gesture);

    for (Prediction prediction : predictions) {
        if (prediction.score > 1.0) {

             gesture.cancelClearAnimation();
             gesture.clear(true);

        }
    }
}
```

The gesture is not wiped out until I touch the screen to write a new gesture.

I tried getting rid of the `setFadeOffset(5000)` and the `setFadeEnabled(true)` but it doesn't help. It is as if there is some default behavior in the gesture that prevents it from being manually cleared.

I tried `getGesturePath()` and tried to rewind the path but it didn't help.